# OnChange event throws an error when trying to select the picklist Field

Tags: apex

I have a picklist which gives the below error when trying to select a value.

[image]

**Component:**

[image]

**Controller:**

[image]

Comment: Please copy/paste code as text instead of (or in addition to) screenshots. An image of text with no accompanying actual text is not good accessibility-wise for folks with screen readers. Plus it makes it harder for anyone to help if they want to copy your code and put it in a sandbox or code editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that here is a better approach .

You can add the **"value"** attribute to **"lightning:select"** and after you select value it will be set to the "value" attribute.

Something like this :

```
 <aura:attribute name="picklistValue" type="String" default = ""/>
 <lightning:select aura:id="picklistValue" value="{!v.picklistValue}" onchange="{!c.handleOnChange}"  label="picklist" required="true">
    <option value="">choose one...</option>
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="pumpkin">pumpkin</option>
    <option value="cherry">cherry</option>
    <option value="blueberry">blueberry</option>
    <option value="pickle">pickle</option>
</lightning:select>
```

And JS controller :

```
({
    //handle Picklist Selection
    handleOnChange : function(component, event, helper) {
       var picklistValue= component.get("v.picklistValue");
       alert(picklistValue);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the Single Quote.

Component Code -

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="genderval" type="String" default=""/> 
    
    <lightning:select aura:id="Productreg" name="select" label="Gender" onchange="{!c.onSelectChange}">
        <option value="">choose one...</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
    </lightning:select> 
</aura:component>
```

Controller Code -

```
({
    onSelectChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        var genderVal = component.find("Productreg").get("v.value");
        alert(genderVal);
        console.log (genderVal);
    }
})
```